# Wrong hash filling to JSON, Perl

Tags: json, postgresql, perl, hash

So, i'm making a programm fetching the data as hash from PostgreSQL, which uses a couple JSONs as parameter file and output datafile respectively. And i had some problem with fetching what it shouldn't fetch. Here's parameter json:

```
{
    "queries": [
        {
            "table_name" : "t1",
            "subqueries": [
                {
                    "query_id" : "t1_1",
                    "query": [
                        .....some sql query
                    ],
                    "to_hash" : { 
                        "target_by" : "type_id",   // key to index by
                        "keys" : [
                            {
                                "source" : "name", // key in hash from db
                                "target" : "name"  // key in new hash
                            },
                            {
                                "source" : "r",
                                "target" : "r"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "query_id" : "t1_2",
                    "query": [
                        .....some sql query
                    ],
                    "to_hash" : { 
                        "target_by" : "type_id",
                        "keys" : [
                            {
                                "source" : "m",
                                "target" : "m"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

....and here's a perl subroutine:

```
my $fname = "query_params.json";

my $q_data_raw;
{
    local $/;
    open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $fname) or oops("$fname: $!");
    $q_data_raw = <$fh>;
    close($fh);
}
my $q_data = JSON->new->utf8->decode($q_data_raw);
my %result;

sub blabla {

    my $data = shift;
    my($tab, $i) = ($data->{table_name}, 0);

    if ($data->{subqueries} ne "false"){
        my %res_hash;
        my @res_arr;
        my $q_id;
        foreach my $sq (@{$data->{subqueries}}){

            my $query = "";
            $q_id = $sq->{query_id};
            print "\n";
            print "$q_id\n";

            for(@{$sq->{query}}){
                $query .= "$_\n"; 
            }

            my $t_by = $sq->{to_hash}{target_by};
            my $q_hash = $db_connection->prepare($query);           
            $q_hash->execute() or die( "Unable to get: " . $db_connection->errstr);

            while(my $res = $q_hash->fetchrow_hashref()) {
                # print Dumper $res; #print #1
                for(@{$sq->{to_hash}->{keys}}){
                    # print "\nkey:\t" . $_->{target} . "\nvalue:\t".$res->{$_->{source}}; #print #2
                    $res_hash{$q_id}{$res->{$t_by}}{$_->{target}} = $res->{$_->{source}};
                }
                $res_hash{$q_id}{$res->{$t_by}}{__id} = $res->{$t_by};
                # print Dumper %res_hash; #print #3
            }
            push @res_arr, $res_hash{$q_id};
            # print Dumper $res_hash{$q_id}; #print #4
            # print Dumper @res_arr; print #5

            $result{$tab}{$q_id} = \@res_arr;
            $q_hash->finish();
        }
    }
}

for (@{$q_data->{queries}}){ // hash from parameter json
     blabla($_);
}
my $json = JSON->new->pretty->encode(\%result);
# to json file
```

....and there's what i get:

```
{
    "t1" : {
        "t1_1" : [
            {
                //type_id_1_* - from first query
                "type_id_1_1" : {
                    "r" : "4746",
                    "__id" : "type_id_1_1",
                    "name" : "blablabla"
                },
                "type_id_1_2" : {
                    "r" : "7338",
                    "__id" : "type_id_1_2",
                    "name" : "nbmnbcxv"
                },
                ....
            },
            {
                //type_id_2_* - from second query
                "type_id_2_1" : {
                   "m" : "6",
                    "__id" : "type_id_2_1"
                },
                "type_id_2_2" : {
                   "m" : "3",
                   "__id" : "type_id_2_2"
                },
                ............
            }
        ],
        "t1_2" : [
            {
                "type_id_1_1" : {
                   "r" : "4746",
                   "__id" : "type_id_1_1",
                   "name" : "blablabla"
                },
                   "type_id_1_2" : {
                      "r" : "7338",
                      "__id" : "type_id_1_2",
                      "name" : "nbmnbcxv"
                   },
                   ....
            },
            {
                "type_id_2_1" : {
                    "m" : "6",
                    "__id" : "type_id_2_1"
                },
                "type_id_2_2" : {
                   "m" : "3",
                    "__id" : "type_id_2_2"
                },
                ............
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Somehow, it fetches the queries from other subqueries, what i don't want. And loop seems to be ok, probably. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It seems you don't put anything into `@res_arr` (so it should be empty)? What is the format of the return value of `$q_hash->fetchrow_hashref()`?

Comment: Your `%result` has one key set, `$result{$tab}` -- which should be `t1` by the JSON you show,  but it shows as `t2` in the final print.  The code shows that you print `%res_hash` but then the (top-level) keys should be `t1_1` and `t1_2`.  Unless I misread some of this lot. What data structure does the last print show?

Comment: @zdim yes, i've made a typo, just corrected - it's `t1` in return json, and `t1_1` and `t1_2` are actually in `t1`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland as i know - it's hash object with parametres from sql query. In first sql it's `type_id`, `name` and `r`. second query has `type_id` and `m`

Comment: So the print out you show is of `%result`?  But that's precisely what the code does -- `$result{$tab}{$q_id}` = ...` creates the top-level `t1` key for a hashref, which gets two subkeys (`t1_1` and `t1_2`) obtained by `$q_id = $sq->{query_id};` in the loop over `subqueries` with two `"query_id"`'s from JSON.  What should be different?  What do you mean by "_it fetches the hash keys from every query into one_" ?

Comment: @zdim i mean, it fetches not only `t1_1`'s `query`, but every `query` from other subqueries, and, as you can see in output json - the `t1_1` and `t1_2` have the exact same objects, what i defenetly don't want. That's the problem

Comment: OK, I see.  But I get dizzy from trying to trace such deeply nested structure.  Don't prints help?  Print out values at places where you know what you should get, then review that.  It is hard to follow through all this.

Comment: @zdim updated lil bit my code. Print #1 is ok in both queries. But second shows some strange things: `t1_1` data fetched ok, but `t1_2` returns empty data, attempt to print its content shows `Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at "***.pl" line 154.` (print #2 line);

Comment: @HåkonHægland Updated missed info. When copied the code and cut unrelated pieces from original source, i missed pushing into `@res_arr`, but it exist and not empty. Used as an array of hashes for `%result` hash.

Comment: @genesi5 Ok :) thanks for the update. I deleted my comment about `@res_arr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like i initialized `@res_arr` and `@res_hash` in wrong level - gotta be in `foreach`. The output is kinda what i need. At least i don't have duplicates.

Gotta be sleep more X(

```
.... 
my $q_id;
foreach my $sq (@{$data->{subqueries}}){
    my %res_hash;
    my @res_arr;

    my $query = "";
    $q_id = $sq->{query_id};
    print "\n";
    print "$q_id\n";
    ..........
}
```

Comment: Great that you found it!  I would draw the reason back to the complexity of all that nesting.  (When that gets too bad it often means it's time to write a class.  On the other hand, of course, sometimes we have to just dig into detail, _very_ carefully.)